# Add icon to p:panel?

Tags: jsf, primefaces

how could I add an icon to a component p:panel?

```
<p:panel header="text" />
```

Unfortunately it does not support an "icon" attribute.
So I tried this:

```
<f:facet name="header">
 <h:outputText value="text">
</h:outputText>
 <p:commandLink styleClass="ui-icon ui-icon-comment" />
</f:facet>
```

But this adds a linebreak between the text and the command Link which only shows up as an icon.

Does someone know how I could else do this?
ty

Comment: Have you tried changing the style for the panel itself? I mean, using a custom class that defines an image as the background?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason the icon is causing the text below it to shift downwards is because the `ui-icon` class has a `display: block` style that causes the image to greedily consume the line and push the text down.  The following header facet will build a 2 column table around the image and text forcing the header to display them both side by side.

```
<f:facet name="header">
  <h:panelGrid columns="2">
    <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-comment" />
    <h:outputText value="text" />
  </h:panelGrid>
</f:facet>
```

Comment: ty for your hints! this is not bad, BUT it adds very much space to the header bar. almost 2 times as it is without the grid. I think the grid somehow takes much space for this. But with your hint, I just overwrote the display styling of the ui-icon like `style="display:inline-block;` and voila, it works!

Comment: @membersound Thats a cleaner way to do the same thing.  Glad to help.

Answer (score 3):

This is the way you can add an icon to a panel component:

```
<p:panel header="the header text you want">
    <f:facet name="actions">
        <p:commandLink
            styleClass="ui-panel-titlebar-icon ui-corner-all ui-state-default">
            <h:outputText styleClass="ui-icon ui-icon-help" />
        </p:commandLink>
    </f:facet>
</p:panel>
```